# Persist another object withing a lifecycle event

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Within a given lifecycle callback, can another object be modified and added to the same flush?  Originally, I didn't include a second flush() in the callback and it wasn't being saved.  I try adding one and it is saved but initiates multiple calls to `EntityOne::preFlush()` and I needed to add a flag to ignore the future calls which doesn't seem right.  What is the correct way to do this?

```
<?php
class MyService
{
    public function save()
    {
        //...
        $this->em->persist($entityTwo);
        $this->em->flush();      
    }
}

class EntityOne
{
    /**
    * @var EntityTwo
    */
    private $entityTwo;

    private $preFlushComplete=false;

    /**
    * @ORM\PreFlush
    */
    public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $event)
    {
        if(!$this->preFlushComplete) {
            $this->preFlushComplete=true;
            $this->entityTwo->setTime(now());
            $event->getEntityManager()->persist($this->entityTwo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persisting other entities inside preUpdate of Doctrine Entity Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734814/persisting-other-entities-inside-preupdate-of-doctrine-entity-listener)

Comment: @yivi.  Somewhat but not perfectly.  Currently, I am just using lifecycle callbacks and `onFlush` is not one per the docs, and I would like to be consistent with other portions of the app and just use callbacks.  `preFlush` is a lifecycle callback and I expect there is a way to add `persist` a new entity in that callback, but haven't figured out how.