# Symfony Entity Listener with Swift Mailer and Twig Environment has empty Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony3.x

I have read the [Symfony Documentation on Entity Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html) and [Doctrine Documentation on Entity Listeners](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) in addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22116883/1156476) and [this blog post by Eric Geloen](http://egeloen.fr/2013/12/01/symfony2-doctrine2-entity-listener-as-serice/) but I can not get my listener to do what I want. In this entity I have a field called status, and when this field changes, an email is going to be sent notifying the receiver of the change.

#### Entity

I have an entity `shipmentLine` with the following annotations:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Bundle\ShipmentBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"\Acme\Bundle\ShipmentBundle\Listener\ShipmentLineListener"})
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class ShipmentLine
{
    . . .
}
```

#### Listener

The ShipmentLineListener has implemented the `__construct` and `prePersist` functions:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Bundle\ShipmentBundle\Listener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Acme\Bundle\ShipmentBundle\Entity\ShipmentLine;

class ShipmentLineListener
{
    private $mailer;
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function prePersist(ShipmentLine $shipmentLine, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        /** @var \Swift_Mime_Message $message */
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Entity Listener test')
            ->setFrom(array('my@email.address' => 'Acme'))
            ->setTo(array('my.other@email.address' => 'Tommy (Acme)'))
            ->setBody(json_encode($event), 'text/html');

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

#### services.yml

Lastly I have registered my listener in services.yml

```
entity.entity_listener.shipmentline_update:
    class: Acme\Bundle\ShipmentBundle\Listener\ShipmentLineListener
    arguments: [ "@mailer", "@twig" ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, event: prePersist }
```

The listener fires, and the mail is sent. But both the `$shipmentLine` and `$event` argument is empty. Can someone see if I do anything wrong? I have a hard time seeing any errors from what I have read.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to pull the entity from the PrePersist event.  I'm surprised you are not getting missing argument messages.  I guess you are sure the event is firing.

Comment: Guess I should have given an example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-listener-class

Comment: I could not get that to work, and it looked like it was about event listeners? I get really confused on the Event Listener/Entity Listener subject. The Doctrine documentation says that "An entity listener method receives two arguments, the entity instance and the lifecycle event" - what is the point of the entity instance if it is not available. Actually, the whole listener and subscriber stuff confuses me :)

Comment: I suspect you may be looking at an older version of the Doctrine docs.  Lots changed in 2.4.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Is the Entity Listener and Event Listener connected? Do I need the Event Listener to use Entity Listener? I think perhaps I need to read up on this. A lot.

Comment: No they are two different ways of accomplishing the same thing.  If you follow the entity listener approach then the entity itself will have a prePersist method.  Use this approach if you only need to deal with one entity type and have no dependencies such as a mailer to inject.  The event listener is independent of the entity and will be called for all prePersist event.  This is almost certainly the approach you will want to take.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I think I need to write another question then, because I had problems with getting access to related entities with the event listener. I need to see if status has changed and into what on an entity two levels "down" from the entity that is persisted.

Comment: No problem.  Just keep in mind that doctrine events are very very very limited.  Did I mention that they were limited?  Many workflows that seem like they would be easy to implement using events are in fact impossible due to the inherent limitations.

Comment: I am beginning to see that. I need help finding another way of solving this. Thank you very much for your time.